# How to only show featured products in wooCommerce using function.php function

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am tying to build a function to show specific products on my woocommerce shop page. In other words I'd like to load only a specific **meta_key** (_featured) that has a specific **meta_value** (yes) from the wordpress **wp_postmeta** mysql table.

In other words I am trying to build a

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
    function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
      $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
        if ( 'featured' == $orderby_value ) {


            $args_sort_cw['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
            'meta_value' = 'yes'
            $args_sort_cw['order'] = 'desc';
            $args_sort_cw['meta_key'] = '_featured';

        }


        return $args;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
    function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
        $sortby['featured'] = 'Show Featured Products only';

        return $sortby;
    }
```

Comment: Why not to use the shortcode for featured products?

Comment: @Fernando Baltazar Because I need also make one for other meta_key (featured, recommened, onsale, new, etc)